# org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: jOOQ; error code [17401]; Protocol violation:

Tags: sql, spring, jdbc, oracle11g, jooq

We are using JOOQ to access database and seeing following error messages in the log lately. Could anyone let me know what does this mean? By the way we are using oracle database.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: jOOQ; uncategorized SQLException for SQL 
[select "company"."employee"."total" from "company"."employee" where ("company"."employee"."id" = ? and "company"."employee"."name" = ?)]; 
SQL state [99999]; error code [17401]; Protocol violation: [ 125, ]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation: [ 125, ]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.jooq.spring.ExceptionTranslator.exception(ExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.jooq.impl.ExecuteListeners.exception(ExecuteListeners.java:232)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:341)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazy(AbstractResultQuery.java:357)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation: [ 125, ]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:669)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:776)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897)
```

Comment: IIRC correctly protocol violation usually means that your driver is too old (or too new) for your database server. You might want to check your JDBC driver version and check compatibility with your server version. And [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227868/protocol-violation-oracle-jdbc-driver-issue) suggests it might also happen if the password of your user is about to expire (which sounds weird to me, but it is the accepted answer).

Comment: We use ojdbc7 and oracle 11.2.0.3. Do you think there is an compatibility issue between these two?

Comment: Ojdbc7 is not a version. It simply means it is for java 7.

Comment: The exact driver version can be found inside of the jar file: `ojdbc7.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I get same exception daily, but always on one particular table, still do you think it could be related to driver incompatibility?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I'm not 100% sure, which is also why I posted as a comment. However if it is happening with a specific table, it might be that you use a feature (column type) that doesn't work in older protocols, or something is communicated in a way that not all driver versions understand. My comment still stands: check your driver version and the compatibility with your server version.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you very much, that really makes sense. I'm on to the suggestion now.